# How to make a multi color map with one shapefile layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, style, categorized-renderer

I am working with a shapefile layer of the world. All the countries are in the Attribute table each one in a different row.
I tried to make each polygon in a different color so the countries will be in a different color, but it did not work.[image]

In the Africa map I save each polygon separately and upload into a new QGIS. This method takes a lot of time. What would a better and faster method be?

[image]

Comment: While it's possible to generate 260+ discrete colors, the ability to distinguish the differences is highly questionable, even among a population without color-blind individuals. You might benefit from research into the [four color theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) and reading the QGIS documentation on thematic mapping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may right-click on the layer in the Layers Panel and go to `Properties >> Style` dialog.

Then, choose `Categorized`, set the field that stores the name of the countries and click the `Classify` button:

[image]

Finally, click the `Apply` button for applying the changes and you will see this:

[image]

Comment: Good one! Didn't know this feature

Comment: @AdamMatan, really easy to use, but very effective at the same time!